# crystal reports performance issue

Tags: crystal-reports

I have report getting data from MySQL and Oracle.I developed the report and my report is running with poor performance.
Somebody suggested me to use db links between MySQL and oracle to pull columns from oracle into MySQL.
What will happen if use db link.Will it improves performance
Please sugggest

Comment: try taking sub reports... one sub report with `MySQL` and other with `Oracle`.

Comment: Hi Siva,  By which approach approach I will improve performance.Joining tables in links tab or using sub reports.Please suggest

Comment: I am not sure about the performance when linking `oracle` and `mysql` but by taking sub report one for oracle and one for Mysql... performance may not get that much affected.

Answer (score 0):

You should post some info to get help: number of rows and columns involved, structure of the query.

Anyway some suggestions:
  - not to filter in the report, but filter passing parameters to the query, when possible
  - not to group in the report but group in the query when possible
  - use indexes in the DB to speed up queries
  - exclude fields not used in the report

Comment: Hi Emanuele If I used DB link between oracle and mysql instead of taking tables from 2 diff databases.Will it improves the performance ?Please suggest.I am taking 2 columns empno,country from oracle and 6 columns from MYSQL. Here master column empno coming from MYSQL and I am linking empno

Comment: Maybe DB link could be not enough. Please post your query to get help